# How to determine local storage if the user is accessing the page for the first time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, local-storage

I Have a Bootstrap 4 accordion, I am very new to the Local Storage concept in Jquery, My codes are below for accordion.
However, I wish to implement

- If the user is accessing the page for the first time- All accordions need the show class append so all accordion is open on page load.
- If the user is accessing the page again, the accordions should be closed on page load remove the show class

```css
.collapsible-link::before {
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  right: 1rem;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


.collapsible-link::after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  right: calc(1rem + 6px);
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.collapsible-link[aria-expanded='true']::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-1px);
}

.collapsible-link[aria-expanded='true']::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
      <!-- Accordion -->
      <div id="accordionExample" class="accordion shadow">

        <!-- Accordion item 1 -->
        <div class="card">
          <div id="headingOne" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
            <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="d-block position-relative text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Collapsible Group Item #1</a></h6>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample" class="collapse show">
            <div class="card-body p-5">
              <p class="font-weight-light m-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Accordion item 2 -->
        <div class="card">
          <div id="headingTwo" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
            <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="d-block position-relative collapsed text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Collapsible Group Item #2</a></h6>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body p-5">
              <p class="font-weight-light m-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Accordion item 3 -->
        <div class="card">
          <div id="headingThree" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
            <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" class="d-block position-relative collapsed text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Collapsible Group Item #3</a></h6>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body p-5">
              <p class="font-weight-light m-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what have you tried? (the javascript part)

Comment: can you do it with a button? then shows the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) you can test for a variable:

```
const firstTime = localStorage.getItem('firstTime');
if (firstTime == null) {
    $('#accordionExample .collapse').removeAttr("data-parent").collapse('show');
    localStorage['firstTime'] = 'false';
} else {
   $('#accordionExample .collapse').attr("data-parent","#accordionExample").collapse('hide');
}
```

The snippet (fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q71k8oth/1/)):

```js
const firstTime = localStorage.getItem('firstTime');
if (firstTime == null) {
    $('#accordionExample .collapse').removeAttr("data-parent").collapse('show');
    localStorage['firstTime'] = 'false';
} else {
   $('#accordionExample .collapse').attr("data-parent","#accordionExample").collapse('hide');
}
```

```css
.collapsible-link::before {
    content: '';
    width: 14px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    right: 1rem;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}


.collapsible-link::after {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 7px);
    right: calc(1rem + 6px);
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.collapsible-link[aria-expanded='true']::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-1px);
}

.collapsible-link[aria-expanded='true']::before {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
        <!-- Accordion -->
        <div id="accordionExample" class="accordion shadow">

            <!-- Accordion item 1 -->
            <div class="card">
                <div id="headingOne" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="d-block position-relative text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Collapsible Group Item #1</a></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample" class="collapse show">
                    <div class="card-body p-5">
                        <p class="font-weight-light m-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Accordion item 2 -->
            <div class="card">
                <div id="headingTwo" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="d-block position-relative collapsed text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Collapsible Group Item #2</a></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample" class="collapse">
                    <div class="card-body p-5">
                        <p class="font-weight-light m-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Accordion item 3 -->
            <div class="card">
                <div id="headingThree" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" class="d-block position-relative collapsed text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Collapsible Group Item #3</a></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample" class="collapse">
                    <div class="card-body p-5">
                        <p class="font-weight-light m-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```